# Alterar um controle Label quando alterar um controle textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho um controle textbox que é utilizado para receber um CPF ou CNPJ e no mesmo e feito uma verificação para aceitar só números.A label que fica na frente do textbox só aparecer quando é salva a página e mostra o CPF ou CNPJ formatado com mascarra.
Eu queria saber, quando a página já estiver sido salvar e o usuario modificar o CPF ou CNPJ alterar o valor da label quando o textbox perder o focus. 
Já estou usando Utilização: onKeyUp,OnKeyPress e o onBlur, são usados nos 3 para evitar o Ctrl+V , Colar do Mouse ou digitar, são feito tudo em javascript.
No onblur posso chamar 2 function e como pegar o valor do textbox e jogar na label por javascript?

Obrigado que poder me ajudar.

```
/* 
Utilização: 
onKeyUp="RemoverCaracteresEspeciais(this.id);"
OnKeyPress="RemoverCaracteresEspeciais(this.id);"
onBlur="SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" usados nos 3 para evitar o Ctrl+V , Colar do Mouse ou digitar.
*/


function SomenteCaracteresNumericos(idControle) {

    var texto = document.getElementById(idControle).value;
    var textoSeparado = texto.split('');
    var numeros = new Array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
    for (var i = 0; i < textoSeparado.length; i++) {
        var teclaValida = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
            if (numeros[j] == textoSeparado[i]) {
                teclaValida = true;
            }
        }
        if (!teclaValida)
            textoSeparado[i] = '';
    }
    document.getElementById(idControle).value = textoSeparado.join('');
}

function Somente(idControle) {

    var texto = document.getElementById(idControle).value;
    document.getElementById('lblRefCNPJEmitenteFormatado').value = texto; 
}

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefCNPJEmitente" runat="server" Text=""  placeholder=" "  onFocus="javascript:this.select();" onkeypress="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" onKeyUp="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" onBlur="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" onchange="javascript:Somente(this.id);">
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa o `onchange`, dai para pegar o valor usa =

```
var value = document.getElementById('idinputcpf').value;
```

E para setar o valor ao label usa =

```
document.getElementById('idlabel').value = '';
```